# Vancian style spellcasting in Mage the Awakening

Tags: spells, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

The last time I was preparing to put together a Mage:tAw chronicle (well before 2e came out) I came across a series of forum posts talking about basically precasting set spells in a ritual and keeping them at the ready for later. I can recall that at some point one of the posters realized they had recreated Vancian, D&D-style casting and were able to bring significantly more power because of it.

At the time I first read this I didn't understand the spellcasting well enough to follow along with how they did it. When I later went to attempt understanding again, I wasn't able to find the original thread I was following. The thought of that has stuck in my head for years now(in part, I'll admit, because I enjoy Vancian spellcasting) and I would like the option to include this in the future, even if it's just on NPCs.

What options do I have in M:tAw 2e to setup and pre-cast one or more spells for later release?

Answer (score 4):

There's a Time •• rote for just this effect. Check out "Hung Spell" on p.187-188.

Comment: Signs of Sorcery p. 69 adds the spell Living Vessel (Life ••• + Prime •••) which permits using Imbue Item on "any living subject."